# EF Code First 4.1 doesn't support nvarchar(max) at all?

Tags: entity-framework, orm, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

I've spent decent amount of time on this problem and still can't figure out why EF team makes the life so hard using Code First.

**So here is some sample:**

My POCO:

The way I want the thing to look like:

```
public class Post
{
     public int Id {get; set;}
     public string Text {get; set;}
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
        .Property(p => p.Text)
        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");   
}
```

The only thing that works:

```
public class Post
{
     public int Id {get; set;}

     [StringLength(4000)]
     public string Text {get; set;}
}
```

The problem is that when in first case I try to insert anything it gives me: `Validation failed for one or more entities` and the second case doesn't fit my business model.

Am I the only one with this problem? How do I deal with this thing?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Using `Int32.MaxValue` may lead to some problems when connected to a SQL Server database. Using `Int32.MaxValue` in either the attribute or the api throws an exception stating "String column with MaxLength greater than 4000 is not supported". But, using either of the following methods works fine for me in EF 4.1:

You can use the `MaxLengthArritbute`, e.g.

```
[MaxLength]
public string Text { get; set; }
```

Or the fluent API, like so

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {
      modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
        .Property(s => s.Text)
        .IsMaxLength();
 }
```

To enforce the use of `ntext` use one of the following:

```
[MaxLength]
[Column(TypeName = "ntext")]
public string Text { get; set; }
```

Or the fluent API, like so

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {
      modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
        .Property(s => s.Text)
        .HasColumnType("ntext") 
        .IsMaxLength();
 }
```

You may not need the `MaxLength` attribute in this case.

**UPDATE (2017-Sep-6):**

As Sebazzz pointed out in his comment `ntext` (and `text`) has been deprecated in SQL Server 2016. Here is a link to further information:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/deprecated-database-engine-features-in-sql-server-2016

Comment: Please note `ntext` is deprecated. It is not advisable to use it for new development.

Answer (score 4):

Use this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
        .Property(p => p.Text)
        .HasMaxLength(Int32.MaxValue);
}
```

Or this:

```
[StringLength(Int32.MaxValue)]
public string Text { get; set; }
```

Comment: EF team should make a list of "hacks" for Code First :)

Comment: @NazarGargol: They will put one out when it's released. But they'll call it "official documentation"

Answer (score 4):

Using the [MaxLength] attribute without any value, as described in Andre Artus's post, works perfectly.  Under SQL CE it correctly uses "ntext", while under SQL Server it uses "nvarchar(max)".  This is highly desired, but should be made clearer in the documentation.

Comment: If you want to force `ntext` then it's easy to apply `[Column(TypeName = "ntext")]` or `.HasColumnType("ntext")` as I did in my initial post.

Comment: FYI - This was changed in the final EF4.1 release.  It uses nvarchar(max) by default WITHOUT using the [MaxLength] attribute.  This is how it should be. :)

Comment: Good to know that. Looks like I'll have to poke around EF 4.1 anew.

Comment: SQL CE 4 + EF 4.1 it uses nvarchar(4000) not ntext

Answer (score 0):

I used the code below to get nvarchar(max) for a field in database. I am using EF5.

```
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration;
using Lansw.Panels.Domain.Entities;

    namespace Lansw.Panels.DataAccess.Configurations
    {
        internal class ServiceAgreementConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<ServiceAgreement>
        {
            public ServiceAgreementConfiguration()
            {
                Property(t => t.ServiceAgreementText).IsRequired().IsMaxLength();
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem with something like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
        .Property(p => p.Text)
        .IsMaxLength()
        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");
}
```