# Generate ntext/nvarchar column when using Entity Framework Code First and a DBMigration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-ce, entity-framework-6

I'd like to either using the Fluent API or data annotations be able to automatically generate a database migration class for a string column as an `ntext` rather than a fixed length string. How would I do that?

When using Entity Framework v6, with Code First, and SQL Server Compact 4, given a simple C# class such as:

```
public class GameFile
{
    public string Id { get; set; }        
    public string FileData { get; set; }
    public int FileSize { get; set; }
}
```

Then, when adding a new migration:

```
add-migration first
```

the resulting migration class defaults to a `string` column of maximum length `4000`.

```
CreateTable(
    "dbo.GameFiles",
    c => new
        {
            Id = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 4000),
            FileData = c.String(maxLength: 4000),
            FileSize = c.Int()
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);
```

When the database is updated via `update-database`, the table will have a column named `FileData` of type `nvarchar(4000)`.

I've tried adding an attribute of `MaxLength` and/or `Column` to the `FileData` property, but there's no change in the generated migration code.

```
[MaxLength, Column(TypeName = "ntext")]
public string FileData { get; set; }
```

I know if I manually edit the migration code to explicitly declare the `storeType`:

```
FileData = c.String(storeType: "ntext")
```

that the resulting table is created properly.

Comment: take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346155/ef-code-first-4-1-doesnt-support-nvarcharmax-at-all

Comment: As mentioned, those attributes do not have any impact on creating a migration.

Comment: I am able to repro, I would file a bug at Codeplex.

Answer (score 4):

Seems like the bug is fixed for Entity Framefork v6.1.3.

The following definition works as expected - creates `ntext` column.

```
[Column(TypeName = "ntext")]
public string FileData { get; set; }
```

Comment: Just a heads up that: "ntext, text, and image data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead." Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017