# Delete using navigation properties in EF 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-6

I am using EF 6 database modal in my application. I have a table `TBL_USER` which has `1:N` relationship in some other table. One of them is `TBL_USER_CASE` where primary key of `TBL_USER` act as foreign key in `TBL_USER_CASE`.

Now i am deleting some user from `TBL_USER`. Before that i need to delete corresponding entries in `TBL_USER_CASE`. I am using following code for that

```
 private long DeleteUser(long UserID)
    {
        using(VerbaTrackEntities dataContext = new VerbaTrackEntities())
        {
            TBL_USER user = dataContext.TBL_USER.Where(x => x.LNG_USER_ID == UserID).SingleOrDefault();
            if(user != null)
            {
                foreach (var cases in user.TBL_USER_CASE.ToList())
                {
                    user.TBL_USER_CASE.Remove(cases);                          
                }
            }
            dataContext.SaveChanges();
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Here i m getting exception

`Additional information: The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted`

How can i do this operation correctly ??

Comment: Is `TBL_USER_CASE` the `N` of another `1:N` relation?

Comment: @Stefan No it is not

Comment: Normally the error shows you what the problem is in quite some detail. This error describes that there must be some relational inconstancy after your action: for example a `1:N` relation without the matching `1`.

Comment: You might want to try the inner exception to determine which field is causing this issue. If the exception is of type DbValidationException check this link to get some more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5345890/getting-exact-error-type-in-from-dbvalidationexception

Comment: BTW: since your function is called `DeleteUser`; why are you not deleting the user? If that is your goal, you can rely on `cascading deletes` to delete the child relations.

Comment: @Stefan i am first trying to delete the child entities

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if your goal is to delete the user, you can let the framework handle the child-relations. You can try this:

```
private long DeleteUser(long UserID)
{
    using(VerbaTrackEntities dataContext = new VerbaTrackEntities())
    {
        TBL_USER user = dataContext.TBL_USER.
                                 SingleOrDefault(x => x.LNG_USER_ID == UserID);
        if(user != null)
        {       
            dataContext.TBL_USER.Remove(user); 
            dataContext.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Update: can you try this one:

```
private long DeleteUser(long UserID)
{
    using(VerbaTrackEntities dataContext = new VerbaTrackEntities())
    {
        TBL_USER user = dataContext.TBL_USER
                             .SingleOrDefault(x => x.LNG_USER_ID == UserID);
        if(user != null)
        {
            foreach (var cases in user.TBL_USER_CASE.ToList())
            {
                //little modification is here
                dataContext.TBL_USER_CASE.Remove(cases);                          
            }
        }
        dataContext.SaveChanges();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: will it not throw the foreign key violation error ?

Comment: @RajeevKumar: If you haven't altered any `cascading delete` options, it should delete the foreign-key related entries as well.

Comment: Error Occured `{"The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint \"USRCAS_USR_FK\". The conflict occurred in database \"VerbaTrack\", table \"dbo.TBL_USER_CASE\", column 'LNG_USER_ID'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}`

Comment: @RajeevKumar: hmm, I wasn't suspecting that one :|  I posted a last try. If it doesn't work, maybe you can post the entities TBL_USER and 
TBL_USER_CASE as well.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do so himself by reading through the net. I have done this by

```
 System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext oc = ((System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter)dataContext).ObjectContext;
 foreach(var Cases in user.TBL_USER_CASE.ToList())
    {                        
       oc.DeleteObject(Cases);                       
    }                    
    oc.SaveChanges();
    dataContext.TBL_USER.Remove(user);
```