# i got Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, model-view-controller

I got an error in ASP.NET MVC, the problem is in action method called `Save` but I don't know where is it exactly and here is the below error

> System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException: 'Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.'

Customer controller

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Validation;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Vidly.Context;
using Vidly.Models;
using Vidly.VewModels;

namespace Vidly.Controllers
{
    public class CustomersController : Controller
    {
        private  MyDbContext _contex;
        
        public CustomersController()
        {
            _contex = new MyDbContext();
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            _contex.Dispose();
        }

        public IActionResult New()
        {
            var membershipTypes = _contex.MembershipTypes.ToList();
            var ViewModel = new CustomerFormViewModel
            {
                MembershipTypes = membershipTypes
            };
            return View("CustomerForm",ViewModel);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Save(Customer customer)
        {
            if (customer.Id == 0)
                _contex.Customers.Add(customer);
            else
            {
                var customerInDb = _contex.Customers.Single(c => c.Id == customer.Id);

                customerInDb.Name = customer.Name;
                customerInDb.BirthDate = customer.BirthDate;
                customerInDb.MembershipTypeId = customer.MembershipTypeId;
                customerInDb.IsSubscribedToNewsLetter = customer.IsSubscribedToNewsLetter;
           }

           // doing here my logic
           _contex.SaveChanges();
            
            return RedirectToAction("Index","customers");
        }

        public IActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            var customer = _contex.Customers.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);

            if (customer == null)
                 return Content("not found");

            var ViewModel = new CustomerFormViewModel
            {
                customers = customer,
                MembershipTypes = _contex.MembershipTypes.ToList()
            };

            return View("customerForm",ViewModel); 
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var customers = _contex.Customers.Include(c => c.MembershipType).ToList();
            return View(customers);
        }

        public IActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            var customers = _contex.Customers.Include(c => c.MembershipType).SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);

            return View(customers);
        }
    }
}
```

CustomerForm

```
@model Vidly.VewModels.CustomerFormViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "New";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h1>New</h1>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "customers"))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.customers.Name)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.customers.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.customers.BirthDate)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.customers.BirthDate, "{0:d MMM yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.customers.MembershipTypeId)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.customers.MembershipTypeId, new SelectList(Model.MembershipTypes, "Id", "Name"), "Select Membership Type", new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        @*<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="flexCheckChecked" checked>*@
        <label>
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.customers.IsSubscribedToNewsLetter) Subscribed To NewsLetter?
        </label>
    </div>
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.customers.Id)
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting exact error type in from DbValidationException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5345890/getting-exact-error-type-in-from-dbvalidationexception)

Comment: Well - did you **look** at those additional errors in the `EntityValidationErrors` property?? What are they telling you?

Comment: ErrorMessage "The Name field is required." string
  PropertyName "Name" string
but what i will do now i do not want to remove required on property Name

Comment: @turki, can you provide the related code about CustomerFormViewModel?

Comment: aren't you using clientside validation with dataannotations?

Answer (score 2):

It is mainly because some of the required field is null use following method to find exactly what you are missing

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
   //Your code come here
   if (customer.Id == 0)
            _contex.Customers.Add(customer);
        else
        {
            var customerInDb = _contex.Customers.Single(c => c.Id == customer.Id);

            customerInDb.Name = customer.Name;
            customerInDb.BirthDate = customer.BirthDate;
            customerInDb.MembershipTypeId = customer.MembershipTypeId;
            customerInDb.IsSubscribedToNewsLetter = customer.IsSubscribedToNewsLetter;
       }

       // doing here my logic
       _contex.SaveChanges();
        
        return RedirectToAction("Index","customers");
}
```

And put the debug point at if condition and run the program in debugging mode
when the pointer comes to if condition mouse over if if it shows fail then clic over it to see what you are missing

Answer (score 1):

Check your **Table** if you have `Not Null` columns, you must add values to those columns in your `customers entity`  before `saveChanges()`

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how many fields are in the database table you're trying to save to, it may be easier and quicker to just check to make sure the object you're trying to save to the database has the correct data types and also you are supplying a value for any fields marked "not null".  I looked up a fancy "catch" statement and added it, which told me what was wrong from here:

https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1012001/VALIDATION-FAILED-FOR-ONE-OR-MORE-ENTITIES-SEE-ENT

But aftwerwards I was mad I just didn't check the database model first.  It was such a simple problem and easy to fix.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was that I was not validating in the model the number of characters allowed in a property with respect to the design of the database

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).